# i installed eclipse via terminal and installed i want to know where sdk is located

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, android, eclipse

I installed eclipse (ultimate edition 3.5) in Ubuntu 12.04 via the terminal. I also installed the ADT plugin in the eclipse program via install new software. Everything has completed but eclipse is asking  for the location of sdk. Where is sdk located on my computer?

Comment: Please run `cd $HOME && ls | grep android` and see if that helps you find the location of the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download Android sdk manually from Android official [website](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=sk).

Download the file and extract it wherever you want.

Now open your eclipse and go to **Window** → **Preferences** → **Android** → **SDK Location**  and click on browse button to select the exacted sdk folder.

You can also use [ADT Bundle](https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030.zip) which is preconfigured with all components in portable form

Please see [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html) for more information.

Comment: i just did like u said but when i click on it, it will say open with and ask me to select the application to open eclipse, i cant open the eclipse

Comment: what is the extension of file you have downloaded. However if something went wrong this is the exact link of the file you need to configure your existing updated eclipse environment. http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6-linux.tgz

Comment: it says executable, it is working in 10.04 ubuntu but not in this version why?

Comment: Try to open it using terminal. first `cd <path_to_folder>` and then `./<file_name>`

Comment: i did i went to the folder where i upzipped adt and took terminal and typed eclipse and when i tried to start sdkmanager an error messege shows. i have taken a screen shot of it

Comment: upload the screenshot at http://imgur.com/

Comment: uploaded please check

Comment: pls provide the link of your upload so that i can see it.

Comment: http://imgur.com/rvQNYlr&vAVq9G8

Comment: open terminal and `cd <SDK_folder/platform/platform-tools>` and `chmod 770 adb` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

- Download latest sdk from [here](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6-linux.tgz)
- Extract file using below command.

  ```
  tar -zxvf DOWNLOAD-FOLDER/android-sdk_r22.6-linux.tgz
  ```
- Move this folder where you want to keep your Android SDK.
- Open Eclipse  ***Window → Preferences → Android → SDK Location*** & set sdk location to your extracted SDK folder.
- Next you need to download google API from **Android SDK manager**.
- Click on Android SDK manager, select components you want to install & click on `Install Packages`.

Or best option is download **[ADT Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download)** which contains Eclipse, ADT & Android SDK inbuilt.

**EDIT :**

---

Might be adb don't have execute permissions. Try below command to correct permissions.

`chmod -R +x /media/New\ Volume/softwares/ADT\ Ubuntu/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/*`

Comment: i did as u told and installed api, but this error is shown
`Unable to run 'adb': Cannot run program "/media/New Volume/softwares/ADT Ubuntu/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb": java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied.
Starting ADB server failed (code -1).`

Comment: Might be adb don't have execute permissions. Try below command to correct permissions.
chmod -R +x /media/New\ Volume/softwares/ADT\ Ubuntu/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/*

Comment: i installed ubuntu as a dual boot in my lap, windows was there with an adminstrator account is this the problem?

Comment: dual boot is not a issue with your eclipse setup. Have you tried after changing permissions?
can you send the output of **mount | grep "New Volume"**

Comment: `mukund@mukund-ThinkPad-Edge-E431:/media$ mount | grep "New Volume"
/dev/sda7 on /media/New Volume type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)`